# Cannot figure out where the tmp folder is to add the .htaccess file per http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003

Tags: 7

That doesn't make any sense to me. I do not have a tmp folder anywhere outside the root. I cannot find the `/tmp` folder supposedly outside the folder where my Drupal instance is located. Well, let me correct that. I found one, but placing the recommended `.htaccess` file in it didn't solve the error message. It didn't seem to be the correct tmp directory. Maybe I don't fully understand where outside the root dir is at? Isn't it the directory above where the installation is at? Is it in the html folder, the sites folder, or above the html folder?

Will the instructions in http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003 work if I create a tmp folder in the html folder? Where exactly do I create the tmp directory?

Comment: @Mołot, I believe this new question is a *follow-up* question that is posted because the OP was unable to make use of the previous answer to the question you've nominated as a duplicate. The dialogue used to nominate for deletion a follow-up question mis-posted under another question *encourages* people who cannot use existing answers to "ask a *new* question".  This is exactly what the OP has done here.

Comment: @FreeRadical OP did not mention he seen the older question at all, and the accepted answer starts with *browse to admin/config/media/file-system* - the very instruction about finding out where these directories are. I don't see a follow-up here, I see the same question, the same problem with finding out where to put files, and the same solution. Just slightly different words. If it's a follow up, and OP already knows where to browse, why do you repeat it in your answer? There should be no need to do so.

Comment: @Mołot, this question is *not* about *admin/config/media/file-system* (the OP already knows that, I just included it for context).  The new question is: How do you locate the path you *find* mentioned on that page (i.e. `/tmp`) in the server's file system?  This is a new question and it has not AFAIK not been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I don't fully understand where outside the root dir is at? Isn't it the directory above where the installation is at?  Is it in the html folder, the sites folder, or above the html folder?

The `tmp` folder is where your configuration says it is.

I looks like you've already navigated to *Administration » Configuration » Media  » File system*, and found that the field "Temporary directory" says `/tmp` - so that is where it is (this is also the default location).

Now, this is a *file system* path, not a Drupal path.  The "/" in front tells you it is in the file system *root*.

To navigate to it, use the following command in the Gnu/Linux CLI:

```
 cd /tmp
```

> Will the instructions in http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003 work if I create a tmp folder in the html folder?

No.

> Where exactly do I create the tmp directory?

You *don't* create it.  It should already exist on your system.

To fix the error message regarding the `.htaccess` in `/tmp` related to the [security update](http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003) you mention, do as follows:

First, in the GNU/Linux CLI, use the following two commands:

```
 cd /tmp
 rm .htaccess
```

Then in the Drupal GUI, as admin, navigate to *Administration » Configuration » Media  » File system*.  Do not change anything, but press "Save configuration".  This will make Drupal create the correct `.htaccess` in the right place.

Comment: Please note that `rm .hraccess` should be `rm .htaccess` to anyone that didn't catch that.

Comment: @Christia, thanks for ctaching that typo. Corrected now.